# Link redirecting assistance

Tags: javascript, css, if-statement, shopify, redirect

Here's the script:

```
<script>
if(document.location.href.indexOf('https://thedomain.com/collections/all?sort_by=best-selling') > -1) { 
document.location.href = 'https://thedomain.com/pages/bestsellers';
}
</script>
```

Question is, how can i make the code so that when i put https://thedomain.com/////////////////////////////////////////collections/all?sort_by=best-selling

How to incorporate
var correctURL= document.location.href.replace(/([^:]/)/+/g, "$1");
whenever i duplicate any of the "/" "?" "_" "=" "-" characters in the web link.

Bottom line is i don't want to be forced to do this (its inefficient):

```
<script>
if(document.location.href.indexOf('https://thedomain.com/////////////////////////////////////////collections/all?sort_by=best-selling') > -1) { 
document.location.href = 'https://thedomain.com/pages/bestsellers';
}
</script>
```

Comment: you can use regex, but you have a bigger problem of why your url is nested 100 layers deep.  Fix that first

Comment: thats the thing, i dont want to make a nest of scripts for each character. is there an effecient way of doing it?

Comment: You know, it's better if you do not do a redirect like this. It has a very high negative impact on SEO and UX

Comment: its ok, only my competitiors will visit that link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you were asking , or why your url will ever have that many slashes in it , but you can just match just part of the url to see if the user is on the correct page.

```
if(document.location.href.indexOf('/collections/all?sort_by=best-selling') > -1) { 

     document.location.href = 'https://thedomain.com/pages/bestsellers';
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot this helped me reduce the script to 20 lines